# What type of certificate spring-boot application needs to have HTTPS connection?

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, https

I would like to make clients require HTTPS protocol to connect to my spring-boot backend application but I have no idea what kind of certificate I need for this.

Any certificate is good for this? Or I need to "turn on" some configurations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, best you can do is to generate self-signed certificate.
There are many examples.

Also, you have to configure your backend.

1. Add dependency:

   ```
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
   ```
2. Provide RestTemplate bean:

```java
@Bean
private RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        SSLContext sslContext = buildSslContext();
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);

        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory)
                .build();

        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);

        return new RestTemplate(factory);
    }

private SSLContext buildSslContext() {
        try {
            char[] keyStorePassword = sslProperties.getKeyStorePassword();
            return new SSLContextBuilder()
                    .loadKeyMaterial(
                            KeyStore.getInstance(new File(sslProperties.getKeyStore()), keyStorePassword),
                            keyStorePassword
                    ).build();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to instantiate SSL context", ex);
        } finally {
            sslProperties.setKeyStorePassword(null);
            sslProperties.setTrustStorePassword(null);
        }
    }
```

3. Provide required SSL properties in your application.properties or application.yaml file:

```
server:
    ssl:
        enabled: true
        key-store: /path/to/key.keystore
        key-store-password: password
        key-alias: alias
        trust-store: /path/to/truststore
        trust-store-password: password
```

That's it. Now you can see your Tomcat is starting on 8080 (or another port) (https).

Alternatively, you can use [my spring boot starter](https://github.com/EugeneLesnov/spring-boot-starter-rest)

Answer (score 0):

1, You need a certificate for the application

- there is two kind of certificates: self-signed certificate and ca-issued certificate
- self-signed certificate

  - you can sign a certificate yourself use [keytool](https://community.pivotal.io/s/article/Generating-a-self-signed-SSL-certificate-using-the-Java-keytool-command)
  - self-signed certificate has some disadvantage, browers will show a red alert page when access self-sign certificate site, and client need import the corresponding self-sign ca root certificate to communicate with server
- ca-issued certificate

  - you can get a ca-issued certificate from [let's encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/)
  - ca-issued certificate do not have all those disadvantage mentioned above ,it just work

2, You also need setting some spring boot configurations, see [Spring Boot Docs - How to configure ssl](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-configure-ssl)